# Delete and rename a directory based on condition python

Tags: python, list, directory

I have a directory structure a Port ID and within that Port ID directory have sub-directories of their type and within that Port Type directory *it may or may not have some .jpg files*, such that

```
Port ID- **11852**---> 20Port_1
                  ---> 25Port_1 ---> 1.jpg
                  ---> 25Port_2
                  ---> 25Port_3 --> abc.jpg
                  ---> 75Port_1
                  ---> 75Port_2 --> pqr.jpg
```

So the directory name "11852" consist of 6 sub directories inside it, we have only one type of `20Port` so it is `_1` at the end of its name, likewise we have 3 types of `25Port` so `_1,_2,_3` and so on.

What I wanted to do is go inside each sub-directory of `11852` directory and check if they do consist of any `.jpg` files or not, if not then delete that sub- directory

For instance check inside sub-directory `20Port_1` if it contains any .jpg file or not, since it does not have any file inside it delete the folder `20Port_1`.

Now check `25Port_1` since it has a file inside it keep it as it is. Next directory `25_Port_2` it also doesn't have a file inside it so delete it, next directory `25Port_3`this has a file inside(Now here's the catch) keep it as it is but rename it to its previous group type number i.e change name of `25Port_3` to `25Port_2`,

Similarly rename `75Port_2` to `75Port_1` because `75Port_1` doesn;t contains any file inside it.
So finally my directory structure should look like

```
Port ID- **11852** --> 25Port_1 --> 1.jpg
                   --> 25Port_2 --> abc.jpg
                   --> 75Port_1 --> pqr.jpg
```

I have tried

```
import os
import shutil

fold_list = os.listdir("D/Port ID Folder/11852")

for m in fold_list:
    k=0
    if len(os.listdir('D/Port ID Folder/11852/'+fold_list[k])) ==0:
        x = (fold_list[k].rsplit('_',1)[0]) == (fold_list[k+1].rsplit('_',1)[0])
        if x == False:
            shutil.rmtree('D/Port ID Folder/11852/'+m)
        else:
            val = fold_list[k].rsplit('_',1)[1]
            shutil.rmtree('D/Port ID Folder/11852/'+m)
```

But didn't got the output,
Any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: first take a look at the replies in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory/41447012, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory/41447012#41447012)

Comment: Still couldn't find the solution for my problem

Comment: My suggestion would be that you try to debug the script first. Currently, your script does `shutil.rmtree('D/Port ID Folder/11852/'+m)` regardless of whether x is True or False, and you are calculating `val` without using it anywhere. How can you expect it to work if you don't try to understand what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

src_dir = "D/Port ID Folder/11852"
f_list = os.listdir(src_dir)
print(f'Initial directory listing {f_list}')
retain_list = []

for folder in f_list:
    if len(os.listdir(os.path.join(src_dir,folder))):
        # Folder not empty
        base, n = folder.rsplit('_',1)
        if base not in retain_list:
            retain_list.append(base)
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(src_dir,folder))

f_list = os.listdir(src_dir)
print(f'Directory listing after removing empty folders {f_list}')

for f in retain_list:
    i = 1
    for folder in f_list:
        base, n = folder.rsplit('_',1)
        if f == base:
            os.rename(os.path.join(src_dir,folder),os.path.join(src_dir,f'{base}_{i}'))
            i += 1

f_list = os.listdir(src_dir)
print(f'Final directory listing {f_list}')
```

Output

```
Initial directory listing ['20Port_1', '25Port_1', '25Port_2', '25Port_3', '75Port_1', '75Port_2']
Directory listing after removing empty folders ['25Port_1', '25Port_3', '75Port_2']
Final directory listing ['25Port_1', '25Port_2', '75Port_1']
```

Comment: Yes its completely working fine, If you could please explain the logic behind your code would be great. Thanks

Comment: This works in 2 passes. In the first pass, I only delete the empty folders and keep track of folders to be renamed. In the second pass, I iterate over each folder check whether it is to be renamed and rename it.